# only removing index.php rule works on my NginX and CodeIgniter as rewrite. Why?

Tags: nginx, rewrite, codeigniter

Although I've spent 2 days reading on forums, I still can't get some Codeigniter rewrites working in Nginx. Here is the server configuration:

```
server {
    listen *:80;

    server_name artademy.com www.artademy.com;
    root   /var/www/artademy.com/web;
    index index.html index.htm index.php index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml;

    if (!-e $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1;
    }

    if (!-e $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^/(index.php\?)/(.*)$ /$1/mobile_app last;
        break;
    }

    error_log /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/artademy.com/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/artademy.com/access.log combined;

    ## Disable .htaccess and other hidden files
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    } 

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location /stats {
        index index.html index.php;
        auth_basic "Members Only";
        auth_basic_user_file /var/www/clients/client0/web3/.htpasswd_stats;
    }

    location ^~ /awstats-icon {
                     alias /usr/share/awstats/icon;
     }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9012;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }
 }
```

Codeigniter settings are: well for uri_protocol: REQUEST_URI;

What I noticed is that from this rule: `rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1;` it works, but if I write it like this: `rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?;`. It might be a wild guess but it stops at the question mark.

Anyhow what I need are rules as these from `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=([a-z]{2})$ 
RewriteRule    ^([a-z]{2})$   index.php?/home_page?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule    ^([a-z]{2})$   index.php?/home_page?lang=$1 [L,QSA]

#how_it_works
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule    ^how-it-works/(en)$   index.php?/how_it_works?lang=en [L,QSA]

#order_status
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule    ^order-status/(en)$   index.php?/order_status?lang=en [L,QSA]
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and show me a proper way for at least one rule? It would be more than helpful.
Thank you in advance! ^^

PS: I made it work on apache by using Path_info for uri_protocol. If this info is of any help. I remember having kind of the same problem there too but switching to path_info made it all good.

PS.2: My .htaccess is working fine, that I am sure. 
For example I want to rewrite from artademy.com/how-it-worksES/es to arademy.com/index.php?/how_it_works?lang=es

Comment: Your Nginx's rewrite rule does not correspond to the Apache's `.htaccess`. Please give us an example of URL and what you want to rewrite to. Moreover, are you sure your `.htaccess` is working fine?

Comment: .htaccess is working fine, i posted it as an example for what i need on nginx. I edited with a PS2 for a clear example of what i need

Comment: how-it-works**ES**?

Comment: the ES is just a temporary thing until the final url are decided. anyhow, try showing me without "ES"

Comment: This sentence does not make sense to me: "Codeigniter settings are: well for uri_protocol: REQUEST_URI;" Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Converting Apache `.htaccess` rewrite rules into Nginx rewrites is not a one-to-one process. You might find [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html) useful.